# How to display a text without the last 15 characters but on resubmit to submit the whole text?

Tags: php, html

I've got log page on my user's panel, where people can see their latest `Hardware ID` number (grabbing it from the table which is running on MSSQL Server 2005) with which they've logged into. I'm displaying it like that (below) to make sure that the latest 20 characters are displayed with `x` only and it's displayed in a drop-down menu where they can select it.

```
'hwid' => substr_replace($row['HWID'], 'x', -20),
```

However, they can use this HWID to submit a form on the drop down menu and if they do that, it will be submitted as it's displayed. So, how I can display it like that without the latest characters but somehow, hiddenly, to submit back from the drop-down menu the full HWID number?

Example: Drop down shows only like that to pick: `da45cba96982x` but if they RE-submit to submit to the server the full one: `da45cba969829nah2bkanzh2hz`
It's just example.

Please let me know if you have an idea?

Comment: Is the HWID sensitive? For example, is it a security problem if the user could figure out the HWID by looking at the source code, or is it concealed just for convenience?

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't specified that. It's my last option which I am using at this moment however I wanted a way to avoid displaying it normally. I mean they can look at the source code and figure it out. It's not security concern since they cannot change it but it's better to be not shown at full. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

your option element should be in below format:

```
<select>
<option value = "full_code">Short Code</option>
</select>
```

This way it will show short code with limited character in dropdown but when form is posted you will get full value.

Hope this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't specified that. It's my last option which I am using at this moment however I wanted a way to avoid displaying it normally. I mean they can look at the source code and figure it out. It's not security concern since they cannot change it but it's better to be not shown at full. Is there any other way?

Comment: in that case you can encrypt while showing `full_code` and once posted you can decrypt the same.

Comment: Is there any example how I can the encrypt and decrypt functions?

Comment: Use simple [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) with PHP. :)

Comment: @Monk25 If this has helped then please up vote and accept my answer.

Comment: @Monk25 Let me know if you are still stuck at somewhere.

Comment: Testing it out now. Will let you know shortly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

@PHP Weblineindia's answer is probably what you're looking for, but if the HWID is a sensitive field, you might want to map it to some other id which you then use to populate the form, eg:

```
<select>
    <option value="simple_id">Short Code</option>
</select>
```

and then on the server, map `simple_id` back to the 'real' HWID.  This way, only the xxx-ified version is ever delivered to the browser.

Comment: Exactly what I need. So, I should query the database once again on submiting to submit the top 1 HWID found for this user just the way I am displaying it (but to be full instead of only first characters)?

Comment: Yes, you'll have some data somewhere which relates the simple id to the 'full' hwid (maybe the simple id is an auto-increment field in a db or something).  How you identify which one they selected is up to you.  E.g: could be there's a 'selected' column in your db table which you set to 1 for that row.